# Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request

Tags: google-app-engine

Getting "Process moved to a different machine" in the log  for the 8 requests on  java back-end and than 
"Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request" and  back-end version hangs and does not serve any requests any more. 
Such thing  happens once a day and only version restart helps.
Is this a bug in Google ?